# How to change my bibliography title using bibtex and miktex 2.9

Tags: bibliographies, babel, naming

I have a problem changing the title of my bibliography using bibtex and miktex 2.9.
I've read varius sources already and tried different things, but the answer that popped up most and should be working well

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}
```

does somehow not work for me. I will give you my full preamble, hopefully someone can find out what mistake I'm doing.
I'm using TeXworks on a Windows 7 PC if that's of any help:

```
%-------------------
%BEGIN
%-------------------

%Wir verwenden eine DIN-A4-Seite und die Schriftgroesse 12.
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 


%Diese drei Pakete benoetigen wir fuer die Umlaute, Deutsche Silbentrennung etc.
%Apple-Nutzer sollten anstelle von \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} das Paket \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} verwenden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{CJK}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}

%Schoenere Schrift
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

%Das Paket erzeugt ein anklickbares Verzeichnis in der PDF-Datei.
\usepackage{hyperref}

%Das Paket wird fuer die anderthalb-zeiligen Zeilenabstand benoetigt
\usepackage{setspace}

%Einrueckung eines neuen Absatzes
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

%Definition der Raender
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry} 

%Abstand der Fussnoten
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}

%Regeln, bis zu welcher Tiefe (section,subsection,subsubsection) Ueberschriften angezeigt werden sollen (Anzeige der Ueberschriften im Verzeichnis / Anzeige der Nummerierung)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%author,date citation style
\usepackage{authordate1-4}

%Section modifications
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large}

%indentation after section heading
\usepackage{indentfirst}



%for japanese
\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}
%-------------------
%Ende des Kopfbereiches
%-------------------

%-------------------
%Hier beginnt der Text deiner Hausarbeit
%-------------------
\begin{document}


%Beginn der Titelseite
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{small}
\vfill {
\noindent
Universitaet }
\end{small}


\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\vfill {\textsf{\textbf{
Titel
}}}
\end{Large}
\end{center}

\begin{small}
\vfill 
\noindent
asdasdasd
27. Juli 2012
\end{small}

\end{titlepage}
%Ende der Titelseite


%Inhaltsverzeichnis (aktualisiert sich erst nach dem zweiten Setzen)
\tableofcontents
% Ab hier wird mit arabischen Zahlen nummeriert, fuer roemische waere es romanic
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%Beginn einer neuen Seite
\clearpage

%Anderthalbzeiliger Zeilenabstand ab hier
\onehalfspacing

\pagestyle{plain}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% BLIOGRAPHIE
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\nocite{*}
\clearpage
\singlespacing
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis}
\end{document}
%-------------------
%END
%-------------------
```

I'd be grateful for any help, for me, the section-title always reads "References" even though I used the ngerman babel package.

Update 1:

changing

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
```

to

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
```

didn't help.

Update 2:

This is a minimum working example which produces for me References as header for the Bibliography:

```
%Wir verwenden eine DIN-A4-Seite und die Schriftgroesse 12.
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,ngerman]{scrartcl} 


%Diese drei Pakete benoetigen wir fuer die Umlaute, Deutsche Silbentrennung etc.
%Apple-Nutzer sollten anstelle von \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} das Paket \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} verwenden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\bibname}{Literatur}

%author,date citation style
\usepackage{authordate1-4}

\begin{document}


%Beginn der Titelseite
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}
%Ende der Titelseite


%Inhaltsverzeichnis (aktualisiert sich erst nach dem zweiten Setzen)
\tableofcontents
% Ab hier wird mit arabischen Zahlen nummeriert, fuer roemische waere es romanic
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%Beginn einer neuen Seite
\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EINLEITUNG
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Einleitung}
This is a minimal working example.
\clearpage

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Section
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Sectionname}
This is a section.

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% BLIOGRAPHIE
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\nocite{*}
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated the MWE again to be even less cluttered. Now it should be pretty much the bare minimums, it still produces References as heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authordate1-4` package alters what you need to do to change the name you want, instead of altering `\bibname` you need to alter `\bibtitle` and `\bibheadtitle`. So add this:

```
\renewcommand{\bibtitle}{Literatur}
\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{Literatur}
```

Somewhen before your `\bibliography` command and all will be well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was already searching hours for a solution, this did it!